# Slow website php (cake php)

Tags: php, cakephp

I have been using cakephp for a while and I did an update recently which made the site very slow only the first time it loads. I have been using different tools to figure out what's causing this but still no clue.

I have been stuck with this for hours. Can someone please help me with this!

Comment: I can only say that you are right. Probably the webserver caches the first request or something? Are you using your own server?

Comment: I have a cloud vps server

Comment: The first time cake needs to create specific cache files (models, persistent, ...). those probably make the first request a little bit slower. additionally, you might request cachable resources like images, css/js files which also might make the first request a little bit slower.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO it has nothing to do on whatever cake is doing, or at least not significantly because if that were the case, it would happen only to the first user and not to all. I loaded your site and it do is slow the first time it loads, but after that it loads just fine.

I'm testing on chrome, and something I found out is that if I delete the cookies (Using Edit this cookie extension) and try load the site again, the request is slow.

I analyzed your site using YSlow extension and found out this (text are taken from analysis result)

- **Grade F on Use cookie-free domains**. There are 22 components that are not cookie-free. When the browser requests a static image and sends cookies with the request, the server ignores the cookies. These cookies are unnecessary network traffic. To workaround this problem, make sure that static components are requested with cookie-free requests by creating a subdomain and hosting them there.
- **Grade F on Make fewer HTTP requests**. This page has 12 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one. This page has 11 external background images. Try combining them with CSS sprites. Decreasing the number of components on a page reduces the number of HTTP requests required to render the page, resulting in faster page loads. Some ways to reduce the number of components include: combine files, combine multiple scripts into one script, combine multiple CSS files into one style sheet, and use CSS Sprites and image maps.
- **Grade F on Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)**. There are 42 static components that are not on CDN. User proximity to web servers impacts response times. Deploying content across multiple geographically dispersed servers helps users perceive that pages are loading faster.
- **Grade F on Add Expires headers**. There are 36 static components without a far-future expiration date. Web pages are becoming increasingly complex with more scripts, style sheets, images, and Flash on them. A first-time visit to a page may require several HTTP requests to load all the components. By using Expires headers these components become cacheable, which avoids unnecessary HTTP requests on subsequent page views. Expires headers are most often associated with images, but they can and should be used on all page components including scripts, style sheets, and Flash.

If you also use Google PageSpeed extension you'll get more interesting info regarding your website.

So IMHO, the problem is more related to browser related issues than server (CakePHP) ones.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok I will try that! I used this site: http://www.webpagetest.org and it shows how long every file takes to load. But my biggest concern was time to first byte was 17 seconds and it just point to root url

Comment: This was actually related to me using freegeoip.net who limited their requests to 10000 requests per hour

Answer (score 1):

Checking with firebug, although you have many js and images request, as @pollirrata points out, the js loading time only counts for about 20% of the loading time, and images another 20% (roughly). It is a lot, but as you commented, the root url is the one taking more than half time of loading.

I know this is supposed to go on comments, but I can't do that yet: what kind of update did you do? I'm guessing it's in the main action of the main controller. Are you retrieving a lot of info there? Cake is probably caching the result queries the first time, and that's why it takes less time to load the second time. Are you using containable behavior for the queries (I'm guessing there are queries...)?

Can you do a:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
pr($info);   //that is, dump every variable with info you have here
```

and see how much time does it take to load without the extra weight of the view, to rule that out?

Comment: I just wanted to post something similar; Just loaded the page and the HTML itself took 16 seconds *before* it started to load. Even though the JavaScript/CSS/Image cache headers are sub-optimal, there must be something that's causing this delay. Check your queries. Are you using `RequestAction`? Also, might be worth to check for misconfiguration in `mod_rewrite` or `mod_alias`. Check your Apache log-files for possible errors

Comment: Some other (possible) causes: 1. Are you using dynamic image scaling? If so, are they created 'real time'? 2. You're using 'themed' assets. Are you serving those assets via PHP or have your created a `symlink` or `mod_rewrite` rule? See [Increasing performance of plugin and theme assets](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html)